# Create a trigger that deletes data from 14 days ago

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, triggers, sql-delete

I need to create a trigger that allows me to delete 14 days old data.
I know how to create the DELETE query, but I need to find a way to declare a variable with the current date - 14 days ago.
Important, the date I have is a time-stamp ... yyyy-mm-dd hh: ss: ms !!

La struttura della tabella è la seguente:

```
ID --> type:Int Primary Key
Name --> type:Varchar
Surname --> type:Varchar
registration_date --> type: TimeStamp
```

Someone can help me?? Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a trigger that deletes data from 14 days ago.  A trigger is run only when the data changes.  So, just use a delete statement.

You should schedule such a delete statement to run periodically, probably using an event -- but you might prefer some other scheduling mechanism.

In the meantime, you can also create a view to only see the most recent data:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    where registration_date >= current_date - interval 14 day;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE EVENT delete_old_rows_from_tablename
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
            STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
DO
    DELETE 
    FROM tablename
    WHERE registration_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

Do not forget to enable [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).